# Determine thickness, head and tail of a snake in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I'm trying to analyze an image of a snake and determine the thickest point and which end is the head and which end is the tail.  Here is the original image.

[image]

So far I have processed the image through grayscale, binary and processed the canny contours of the snake.

[image]

I also have the skeleton of the canny via thinning algorithm which is roughly the center line of the snake.

[image]

Now that I have the Canny contours and skeleton contours what techniques could be used to determine the pixel width of the fattest part of the snake body and also determine the head and tail?

[image: c]

I havent been able to find any techniques with OpenCV C++ that I can use to create these measurements or determine head from tail.

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To determine thickest & thinnest parts, you can count black pixels (zeros) between 2 adjacent white pixels in a row in the 1st canny image & store this count in a vector/array. Then you can find max & min from the array to determine the thickest & thinnest points respectively

Comment: hi @umar Thanks for your comment.  I'm not sure I understand your approach as if we're just looking at rows you'll get really wide in some places where the snake body is horizontal and very thin ones at the tail where it gets much narrower.  Max will actually be the largest horizontal section of the snake and Min will always be the tail.  I think it is going to take something a little more sophisticated than that for a reasonably accurate measurement.  I appreciate the help though as I work through this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion, assuming computational cost is not a problem:

- **Thickness:** for each point of the skeleton, the local thickness can be approximated by computing the distance from the current point of the skeleton and each point of the contour and keeping the smallest distance. Then the thickest point is simply the one where the local thickness is maximal.
  `thickness(x_skelet) = min([distance(x_skelet, x_contour) for x_contour in countour])` (yeah I know this is bad python style pseudo code, hope it make sense)
- **Hear/Tail differentiation:** The main difference between head and tail is the average thickness. First off I would define which percentage of the body the tail and head are (at first glance I'd say 5%). Then, using the local thickness defined above I'd compute the average thickness over the 5% points of each side of the serpent. The head should be the side with the highest average thickness. And by definition the tail is the other.

From looking at your image, this should be robust enough to overlook the small artifacts in your image. Know that this implementation of local thickness is a little off close to the extremities but it should be good enough for what you described.

Hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Hi @Loïc Niederhauser , Thanks very much for your suggestion, I think the head/tale differentiation you suggested would be a good approach once we have the thickness data.  We do have some computational limitations as this analysis is likely to be done on a mobile device so there is not unlimited processing power.

Is there a more sophisticated approach we could take that would be more efficient?

Again I really appreciate the support and any additional suggestions you may have.

-Mark.

Comment: Oh, hi Mark! Well if speed is an issue fro computation I have in mind 2 other methods that might work for computing local thickness. First, assuming you stored your images in matrices-like object you could move in a spiral pattern from your origin point, looking for the first white pixel and compute the distance to that point. Second, if your skeleton is very clean, you could compute the local tangent and then only look for the closest point on the line perpendicular to that tangent (this is very noise sensitive). Depending on data structure, one or the other method might be faster.

Comment: As for other ideas improvements I don't see much more to do on that particular problem. You're image processing seem on point and the processed images look clean enough. If you have a GPU or DSP on your device you probably will be able to use is to speed up computations a lot but that's all I got. Btw may I ask what application you're working on? (no worries if for some reasons you can't disclose it)

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach would result in widths orthogonal to and along the skeleton, or even better, orthogonal to and evenly spaced along the (smoothed) medial axis. Ortho-medial widths can then be plotted or, to obtain the head and tail position, easily be analyzed.[image: Ortho-medial widths]

Comment: Why don't you explain how to do this? This seems like a non-answer.

Comment: Obviously the OP is able to compute a skeleton. The rest is geometry: Compute the orthogonal lines to the skeleton at all of its points. The better suited medial axis can be computed per EDM (Euclidean Distance Mapping). There are a lot of EDM-related publications and many websites.

Comment: This seems good in theory, but looking at the number of artifacts on op's skeleton and median axis, do you think this is robust enough? Small errors in the orthogonal vector might result in big overestimation of the thickness.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and question. In short, the approach based on the medial axis is robust! If you enlarge the result plot, you see the original measurements in light gray and of course they show the effect you mention but the deviations from the lowpass filtered graph in blue aren't worrying. I've coded the approach as a Java-plugin for ImageJ that is available from [here:](https://www.gluender.de/Miscellanea/MiscTexts/UtilitiesText.html#Gl-2022-2)

Comment: Oh ok interesting work. Thanks for your answer and your time